# Jest Unit test with React native for firebase analytics

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am new to jest unit test, I need advice on how to write a jest unit test with React native for cover the following lines of code:

```
export const logSeekerMeditationCancelReason = (scene, reason) => {
    logEvent('cancel_reason', scene, { reason });
    logForFBAnalytics(`cancel_reason_${reason}`); };
```

Can some one please help me. Thank you.